# PowerShell - Extract Data between two lines

Tags: powershell, parsing

I'm looking for what I am hoping is a simple thing.  I am trying to pull data from a .csv file, but the data is between two lines of hyphens such as follows:

```
File1

header1,header2,header3,header4
--------------------------------------------------------
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
data1,data2,data3,data4
--------------------------------------------------------
end of file
```

I want only the data between the lines of hyphens to be saved.  I am having trouble finding a way to do this since the lines are exactly the same.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 3:

```
$firstrowfounded=$false

Get-Content "C:\Temp\test.txt" | foreach {
    if ($firstrowfounded )
    {
        if ($_ -like "*--*")
        {
           break 
        }
        else
        {
           $_ 
        }

    }
    elseif ($_ -like "*--*")
    {
       $firstrowfounded=$true 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will grab what you want and output it into `output.csv`

```
$input  = "C:\example\File1.csv"
$output = "C:\example\output.csv"

Get-Content $input | Where-Object {$_ -like "*,*"} | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File $output
```

Now you can just do `Get-Content $output`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
$startend=(Select-String -Path "C:\Temp\test.txt" -Pattern "--------------------------------------------------------").LineNumber
(Get-Content "C:\Temp\test.txt")[$startend[0]..($startend[1]-2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\test.txt" | where {$_ -like '*,*'} | ConvertFrom-Csv
```